# fortran 64 bit hex BOZ

Tags: c++, c, fortran

in C++ this is accepted:

```
uint64_t mask = 0x7FC0000FF80001FFLL;
```

but in fortran

```
integer(kind=8), parameter :: mask = Z'7FC0000FF80001FF'
```

does not work with gfortan.
I think both of them are 64bit values? or not?

gfortran complains:

> arithmetic overflow from converting INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(8)

EDIT:

So, sorry for the confusion, here is some more extended problem description.
I will do some bit shifting in Fortran and have some sample code in c++.
There in the sample c++ code the masks are defines like:

```
typedef uint64_t mask;
static const mask dilate_2 = (mask)0x7FC0000FF80001FFLL ;
static const mask dilate_1 = (mask)0x01C0E070381C0E07LL ;
static const mask dilate_0 = (mask)0x9249249249249249LL ;
```

From my poor c++ understanding, I think that the hex values are 64bit
integer values (they have LL in the ending).
Now in Fortran my problem first was, that the definition with

```
integer(kind=8), parameter ...
```

did not work, as Vladimir said, because

```
integer(kind=8), ...
```

might be no 64bit integer.
Than I tested Alexanders solution, which works for the first and the
second (dilate_2, dilate_1) constant.
Also Vladimirs solution works for these two.
Now for dilate_0 none of these solutions work. I would suppose that Vladimirs solution will cast 0x9249249249249249LL (what is actually
a greater integer than allowed in INT64) into a INT64
if I do:

```
integer(INT64), parameter :: dilate_0 = int(Z'9249249249249249', &
                             kind=kind(dilate_0)
```

But this also don't work and gfortran give me an error:

> Error: Arithmetic overflow converting INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(8) at (1).

So my actual question is how to implement this constant in Fortran?

Comment: What means *does not work*? Do you get some error? Or strange result?

Comment: I edit the question regarding what gfortran says

Comment: Ok, sow you see it is `integer(16)`, definitely not the same as `integer(8)`, which happens to be 64 bit for your compiler. Kind numbers are not portable!

Comment: This code compiles cleanly with gfortran 5.0 and gfortran 4.8.  I suspect a typo (e.g. one hex digit left out).

Comment: @tkoenig not if extensions are disabled, although the message is different.

Comment: I use 4.8.0... in my first question

Comment: Fortran [doesn't have unsigned integers](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/297670). You would have to define your own type and do some magic with `transfer` as described in the post.

Answer (score 3):

As Vladimir posted in his comment `integer(kind=8)` is not portable (and not of kind `16` as the compiler complains).

As a remedy I suggest to use the intrinsic module `ISO_Fortran_env` (Fortran 2003) which has many [predefined constants](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gfortran/ISO_005fFORTRAN_005fENV.html) for the compiler used. Using `INT64` from this module solves your problem and results in portable code:

```
program test
  use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: INT64
  integer(INT64), parameter :: mask = Z'7FC0000FF80001FF'

  print *,mask
end program
```

Comment: I actually don't see any difference from the original code that would prevent the referenced error. Try compiling with `-std=f2008`.

Comment: I really don't see how does it fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

`Z'9249249249249249'` is not representable as a an INT64 (which is equivalent to an `INTEGER(kind=8)` in gfortran) because

- BOZ constants are signed numbers (the same as every other integer constant in Fortran)
- This number is larger than 2**63-1, the largest representable number for an INT64

Gfortran therefore selects the smallest integer type which fits, which is `INTEGER(KIND=16)`.

We then have parameter staement where an `INTEGER(KIND=8)` parameter should be assigned a value outside its range.  This is what the compiler complains about.  It would complain the same way about

```
  INTEGER(KIND=4), PARAMETER :: N = 37094947285
```

If you want to get around this, you can use the -fno-range-check option to gfortran. Information about `-fno-range-check` is already included in the gfortran error message (the part you didn't show).

Answer (score 0):

I would do this to stay standard conforming

```
  integer(whatever), parameter :: mask = int(Z'7FC0000FF80001FF', &
                                             kind=kind(mask))
```

where `whatever` is some kind constant of the required value. It could be `int64`.

The above will not work if the constant corresponds to a negative number. One then has to make a trick like:

```
integer(int32), parameter :: mask = transfer(int(Z'A0000000',int64),1_int32)
```

or

```
integer(int32), parameter :: mask = transfer(Z'A0000000',1_int32)
```

but I am not sure whether the last one is strictly standard conforming.

Comment: hmm when I do the following  integer(int64), parameter ::splitmask_f = int(Z'9249249249249249', kind=kind(splitmask_f)) i get also an error from gfortran

Comment: sorry, I got the same error as in the inital question -> arithmetic overflow from converting INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(8) I use gfortran 4.8.0

Comment: are you 100% sure you have *exactly* the same code? doublecheck, even your original code should work. Does the accepted answer work for you?

Comment: I tested it with program testhex
 use,intrinsic :: ISO_Fortran_env, only: INT64
 integer(int64), parameter ::splitmask = int(Z'9249249249249249',&
                               kind=kind(splitmask))
end program

Comment: gfortran 5 gives me : testgfhex.f95:3:45:

  integer(int64), parameter ::splitmask = int(Z'9249249249249249',&
                                             1
Error: Arithmetic overflow converting INTEGER(16) to INTEGER(8) at (1). This check can be disabled with the option »-fno-range-check«

Comment: @JanWittke Isn't `9249249249249249` the BOZ number evaluated? Why do you need the additional `Z'...'`?